# Angular how to use an attribute directive on <app-root>? (index.html)

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a theme module for my angular application that allows the user to switch between a light/dark mode.
It uses a sevice, directive and seperate module and works fine except when trying to use the direct in `<app-root></app-root>` and this is neccesary because otherwise the theme does not get applied to the whole DOM.

theme.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { THEMES, ACTIVE_THEME, Theme } from './themes/symbols';

@Injectable()
export class ThemeService {

  themeChange = new EventEmitter<Theme>();

  constructor(
    @Inject(THEMES) public themes: Theme[],
    @Inject(ACTIVE_THEME) public theme: string
  ) {
  }

  getTheme(name: string) {
    const theme = this.themes.find(t => t.name === name);
    if (!theme) {
      throw new Error(`Theme not found: '${name}'`);
    }
    return theme;
  }

  getActiveTheme() {
    return this.getTheme(this.theme);
  }

  getProperty(propName: string) {
    return this.getActiveTheme().properties[propName];
  }

  setTheme(name: string) {
    this.theme = name;
    this.themeChange.emit( this.getActiveTheme());
  }

  registerTheme(theme: Theme) {
    this.themes.push(theme);
  }

  updateTheme(name: string, properties: { [key: string]: string; }) {
    const theme = this.getTheme(name);
    theme.properties = {
      ...theme.properties,
      ...properties
    };

    if (name === this.theme) {
      this.themeChange.emit(theme);
    }
  }

}
```

theme.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeService } from './theme.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Theme } from './themes/symbols';

@Directive({
  selector: '[theme]'
})
export class ThemeDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private _destroy$ = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private _elementRef: ElementRef,
    private _themeService: ThemeService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const active = this._themeService.getActiveTheme();
    if (active) {
      this.updateTheme(active);
    }

    this._themeService.themeChange
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$))
      .subscribe((theme: Theme) => this.updateTheme(theme));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._destroy$.next();
    this._destroy$.complete();
  }

  updateTheme(theme: Theme) {
    // project properties onto the element
    for (const key in theme.properties) {
      this._elementRef.nativeElement.style.setProperty(key, theme.properties[key]);
    }

    // remove old theme
    for (const name of this._themeService.theme) {
      this._elementRef.nativeElement.classList.remove(`${name}-theme`);
    }

    // alias element with theme name
    this._elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add(`${theme.name}-theme`);
  }

}
```

theme.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ThemeService } from './theme.service';
import { ThemeDirective } from './theme.directive';
import { THEMES, ACTIVE_THEME, ThemeOptions } from './themes/symbols';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [ThemeService],
  declarations: [ThemeDirective],
  exports: [ThemeDirective]
})

export class ThemeModule {
  static forRoot(options: ThemeOptions): ModuleWithProviders<ThemeModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ThemeModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: THEMES,
          useValue: options.themes
        },
        {
          provide: ACTIVE_THEME,
          useValue: options.active
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Then I declare in the imports of app.module:

```
ThemeModule.forRoot({
      themes: [lightTheme, darkTheme],
      active: 'light'
    })
```

I can use this directive now fine in app.component.html:

```
<body theme>
  <app-nav-menu (toggleTheme)="toggleTheme()"></app-nav-menu>
  <div class="container parent-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</body>
```

however I cant use it in index.html, since it would like to apply this directive to the app-root tag or the html tag itself so that the theme affects the whole DOM.

Any idea how to achieve my goal? any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

On theme.directive.ts try to update this function

```
updateTheme(theme: Theme) {
    // project properties onto the element
    for (const key in theme.properties) {
     // Comment this line
     // this._elementRef.nativeElement.style.setProperty(key, theme.properties[key]);
     // add this line  
   this._elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.setProperty(key, theme.properties[key]);

    }

    // remove old theme
    for (const name of this._themeService.theme) {
      this._elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.classList.remove(`${name}-theme`);
    }

    // alias element with theme name
    this._elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.classList.add(`${theme.name}-theme`);
  }
```